# Why is my plumber suggesting that I replace the poly water supply line to my house?

Tags: plumbing

All the houses in my subdivision were built in 1985, and they all have poly main water lines to the house. My line is spraying water right at the fitting that connects to my water meter.

The plumber tells me the fitting for this type of poly pipe is no longer made nor available, and said everyone with this poly usually just replaces the *whole* line, (for $4500). He recommends Wirsbo Propex. In other words, he says that he can't just cut off the leaking section of line because he has no fittings to reconnect it to the meter. (I'm not sure I can believe all this, as naturally he'd rather do the $4500 repair.)

There are plenty of YouTube poly videos showing how quick and easy DIY it is to add connectors to this line. Some are simply metal inserts that are barbed on one side (inserted into the poly after heating it) and threaded screws on the other, then you screw an adaptor on to connect to any type of line you want, copper, PVC, pex, etc. Thing is, I can't find any of these fittings online, but maybe I just haven't searched enough. I could repair this myself if I could find these fittings.

It also just occurred to me that this poly line is really large, diameter wise, much larger than the 3/4" pipes used in the house. Instead of digging up the whole yard, I'm wondering if I can't snake a smaller diameter (1/2") PEX line through the poly, from the meter to the house. It's a fairly straight shot from what I can tell. It has the added bonus of acting like an insulator/protective covering.

Any thoughts or comments?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Responding to a general request for thoughts and comments is not what we do here

Comment: The answer is **yes**. You should get a few more estimates, as this will also serve to provide you with more info.

Comment: Can you find text (or excavate far enough to find text) on the exterior of the pipe disambiguating wheter it is polyethylene or polybutylene? In my area polybutylene never got any traction for outside of the house plumbing, but evidently that may be possible. PB2110 is a code that's likely for polybutylene.

Comment: Also measure the size of the pipe, please, rather than the ever so precise " really large diameter-wise." You may also find the nominal size (which may be different than the outside diameter) listed among the text on the outside of the pipe if you can read the text.

Comment: Well, the term "Black Poly" was from the plumber. (I'd never heard of it before.) But you can search for videos using "Black Poly" and get a lot of hits on DIY tips. None of the videos specified what KIND of poly it is. I did notice none of the videos were recent; they were dated anywhere from 2010 to around 2017. Searches for poly fittings only turned up landscape irrigation products, not water mains. The part about the pipe size was more about is it possible to leave the line in place and insert a smaller diameter PEX line, without having dig up the whole line.

Comment: The diameter would matter somewhat in assessing whether there were fittings available to fit this pipe, if it is polybutylene. If it is polyethylene, there are definitely fittings to fit it, so establishing that would be step one. Can you photograph and [edit] in a picture of the leak/fitting? An inference can be drawn from certain types of fittings only being common on PB, not PE. Polyethylene has been used for this purpose before, during and after the period when polybutylene was in use.

Comment: If the plumber were to only replace the fitting at the meter (and perhaps some pipe as well); then the fittings and pipe at the house end will still be old and potentially "unreliable" and risk failure there. If the plumber believes that you understand and accept this risk, then they might replace just the fitting for you. (If this is allowed under your local code).

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that we're actually talking about [poly*butylene*](https://www.polybutylene.com/poly.html), which is obsolete and could account for the confusion. I think most of us assumed you're talking about poly*ethylene*, which is commonly used today.

Your home was built during the window in which polybutylene pipe was used for runs from the street to the meter. It was discontinued due to lack of durability:

> While scientific evidence is scarce, it is believed that oxidants in the public water supplies, such as chlorine, react with the polybutylene piping and acetal fittings causing them to scale and flake and become brittle.

This would also explain your plumber's suggestion, which seems reasonable in that case. Due to slightly different wall thickness, commonly available fittings cannot be used. Any plumber who cares to stand behind his/her work may also be reluctant to work on PB, since it's more likely to result in a callback. You might point out that SharkBite offers [transition fittings](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/polybutylene-transition-coupling), which can be identified by their gray plastic sleeves. So a solution may be at hand.

"Black poly" isn't really a thing, officially. It's a layperson's term for an unknown plastic or a tradesperson's nickname for polyethylene that happens to be black. Color is irrelevant with these materials, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your plumber <s>is</s> *might be* a crook/scam artist.

Black poly**ethlyene** pipe (also known as well pipe) for cold water distribution is still very standard and available as are the fittings for it. The folks who make blue polyethlyene well pipe make some dubious claims that it's "better" but I can't say I find them at all convincing, and the price differential is large. The black stuff is listed by NSF as suitable for potable water. So's the blue stuff. They use the same fittings anyway. The rest is marketing BS.

Digging up the whole line to replace it is ludicrous - black polyethlyene is not like the gray butyl they used inside houses for a while that "just fails" and you really should replace the whole set - I've personally worked on black polyethlyene well pipe from 1964 or so, and aside from the misery of getting connectors out of it without just sawing the pipe off (didn't want to lose the length that would take) it was just fine 50 odd years on.

It would be advisable to evaluate why the pipe at your water meter broke (is it exposed to damage? Frost movement or freezing?) but there is no reason at all to replace black polyethlyene with pex, wholesale, particularly if it means digging up the line.

Picture is from Aqua Science, one of **many** online vendors that have them. A hardware store near you probably also has the correct fittings. *I have purchased stuff from Aqua Science but have no other relationship with them.*

[image: barbed fitting for poly well pipe]

Comment: So cynical. :) I think there's a misunderstanding here. Crooks happen, but mistakes happen more often.

Comment: If it *is* Polybutylene, **polybutylene repair fittings** are still available, and given that the pipe is buried outside rather than in the walls of your house, using a repair coupling and a short section of other pipe is perfectly reasonable when the alternative is a $4500 excavation job. Yup, I'm cynical...and skeptical.